# Extracting Big Wav file into smaller chunks in Java

Tags: java, wav

I have a big wav file that I would like to get into smaller chunks. I also have a .cue file that have the frame rate lengths, at which the smaller chunks should be.  I figured out how to split the wav up, but all the wav files that are made are the same sound. It seems that everytime I create a new wav the big wav file is starting from the beginning and making the new wave the correct length but same sound.

I think I need a way to read the wav to a specific frame, then write to a file, then continue reading and write to another file,etc...

I've been at this for hours and can't seem to figure it out.  any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code,  all the commented stuff is my wrong code that I have been trying.

```
 int count2 = 0;
  int totalFramesRead = 0;
        //cap contains the how many wav's are to be made
        //counter contains the vector position.
        String wavFile1 = "C:\\Users\\DC3\\Desktop\\wav&text\\testwav.wav";
            //String wavFile2 = "C:\\Users\\DC3\\Desktop\\waver\\Battlefield.wav";
            while(count2 != counter){
            try {
                    AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
                    int bytesPerFrame = clip1.getFormat().getFrameSize();
                    //System.out.println(bytesPerFrame);
//                     int numBytes = safeLongToInt(clip1.getFrameLength()) * bytesPerFrame; 
//                     byte[] audioBytes = new byte[numBytes];
//                     int numBytesRead = 0;
//                     int numFramesRead = 0;
//                     // Try to read numBytes bytes from the file.
//                     while ((numBytesRead = 
//                       clip1.read(audioBytes)) != -1) {
//                       // Calculate the number of frames actually read.
//                       clip1.read(audioBytes)
//                       numFramesRead = numBytesRead / bytesPerFrame;
//                       totalFramesRead += numFramesRead;
//                       System.out.println(totalFramesRead);
//                     }

                    long lengthofclip = Integer.parseInt(time.get(count2))- silence;

                    globallength = clip1.getFrameLength();
                    AudioInputStream appendedFiles = new AudioInputStream(clip1, clip1.getFormat(), lengthofclip);
                    //long test = (appendedFiles.getFrameLength() *24 *2)/8;
                    //int aaaaa = safeLongToInt(test);
                    //appendedFiles.mark(aaaaa);
                    AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                            new File("C:\\Users\\DC3\\Desktop\\wav&text\\" + name.get(count2)));
                            count2++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
  }
  public static int safeLongToInt(long l) {
    if (l < Integer.MIN_VALUE || l > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
            (l + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value.");
    }
    return (int) l;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought at first glance but I'm assuming it's this line giving trouble:

```
AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
```

Take that and put it outside of your while loop so it doesn't get recreated every cycle. Like so:

```
//...
    String wavFile1 = "C:\\Users\\DC3\\Desktop\\wav&text\\testwav.wav";
    AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
    int bytesPerFrame = clip1.getFormat().getFrameSize();

        while(count2 != counter){
        try {
//...
```

This also assumes that your algorithm is correct, which I'm not going to waste time thinking about because you didn't ask that question :-D